# SFML library can't find .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I implemented the `SFML` library nightly build to my Visual Studio 2013, because the original one is not compatibile with this VS version. I done everything what is needed (added directory to `include` folder in both Debug and Release, added directory to `.dll` files), but it can't find the files in program. What else should be done to make this library work? Or should i consider changing Visual Studio to 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given really to much information so I am just really guessing as to what the problem is.

> added directory to .dll files

But that sounds like your problem right there. You don't add the directory that the .dll files are in to your project. The only directories you need to add to the project are the include directory and the library directory.

But anyways I am assuming you are using dynamic linking since otherwise you wouldn't be dealing with .dlls. Now different IDE's require that you place the .dlls in different spots but since you are dealing with VS2013 you need to copy whatever .dlls that you are using into the same folder where your program's compiled executable is (The .exe file).

Another option is to link statically instead of dynamically which I generally prefer to do on small projects but it is really up to the developer which he prefers.

When you link statically you don't need to include any .dlls. What you will need to do is recompile SFML's sources and make sure to build the library so it produces the static library files (They should be named something like sfml-graphics-s-d.lib for debug and sfml-graphics-s-d.lib for release).

Add that library directory which contains the static library files to your project and then link to them .lib files in VS's input window (Remember that -d is for the debug build).

Next you will need to add `SFML_STATIC` to your preprocessor options on both the release and debug build.

After that you are good to go and don't need to include the .dll files with your project. And again whether you choose to link dynamically or statically is really up to you and the project you are working on but for small projects I would suggest linking statically.

Comment: For me the .dll files are called sfml-graphics-2-d.dll for debug and sfml-graphics-2.dll for release (just to be clear). I managed to add them to folder and it seems to work properly for now. But what am I going to do when I want to publish the application. Just include .dll files in the application resources directory?

Comment: The naming for the .dll file shouldn't really matter as long as you are correctly putting the debug .dll's with the debug executable and the release with the release executable. Also glad to hear that it works now :)! When you wish to release your application yes you will need to include the .dll files with your release for it to work. This is another reason why I like to link statically. If you don't want to include all them .dll files in your release of your application you might want to consider looking into linking statically instead.

Comment: No, it's totally fine for me to add the .dll files. Thanks for help!